# read file and put values in a list

Tags: list

I am new to python..I mean brand new and I have to extract and print (or save in a txt) the values on column #8 from a txt file that looks like this:

PDE    1980  01 01 020925.70  36.21 -120.85   5  3.2 MLBRK   ... .......

so basically, for each line, I need to select only the '3.2'..

so far I have:

```
import sys
import numpy


text_file = open("earthquake_catalog_example.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')

Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Magnitude, Value9,         Value10, Value11, Value12 = lines.split(" ") 
Value1 = str(Value1) 
Value2 = float(Value2)
Value3 = float(Value3)
Value4 = float(Value4)
Value5 = float(Value5)       
Value6 = float(Value6)
Value7 = float(Value7)
Magnitude = float(Magnitude)
Value9 = float(Value9)
Value10 = str(Value10)
Value11 = str(Value11)
Value12 = str(Value12)

print lines
print len(lines)
```

but get an error:  'list' object has no attribute 'split'

thanks

Comment: Try doing a search on the error: https://www.google.com/search?q=list%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27split&oq=list%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27split&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1225j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8